# XSLT function parameter from xsl:value-of select

Tags: xml, function, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

I want to substring a particular sentence in XSLT so I use below function and it works fine.

```
<xsl:value-of select='substring("This is My String",2,6)'/>
```

But what I want to do is provide a "This is My String" as a value from XSLT expression like below.

```
<xsl:value-of select='substring(<xsl:value-of select="searchpage/header/para[2]/text"/>,2,6)'/>
```

If I do this it gives me below error.

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this :

```
<xsl:value-of select='substring(searchpage/header/para[2]/text, 2, 6)'/>
```

You can use the value retrieved by your XPath expression directly in the `substring()` function.

**Note:** in your XPath, you expect to have a `<text>` tag within the `<para>`. Hope you don't confuse with the XPath `text()`.